# Change float value based on element width

Tags: html, css

I have 2 Elements that have fluid widths and float each other. One element is on the left and the other on the right.
When there is not enough space the second element breaks to the next line.
If this happens, I would love for it not to be right aligned (float:right) but be left aligned.

```css
ul {
  width: 250px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  clear: both;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: inside none;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  background: #2FCC71;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  background: #3598DC;
}
/* just for clearing floats */

ul:before,
ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<h2>short right element</h2>
<ul>
  <li class="left">Left Element</li>
  <li class="right">Right Element</li>
</ul>
<h2>Problem: long right element is right aligned</h2>
<ul>
  <li class="left">Left Element</li>
  <li class="right">Right Element with longer text</li>
</ul>
<h2>what I would love: if right aligned element breaks, make it left aligned:</h2>
<ul>
  <li class="left">Left Element</li>
  <li class="right" style="float:left">Right Element with longer text</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: No, CSS cannot detect overflow/linebreaks.

Comment: ...at least not with floats...

Comment: If You use Bootstrap css and Bootstrap Grid system then easily it will be solve. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: please choose a better title. the title doesn't explain the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do that...with `white-space:nowrap`.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ZOxYXK)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrap {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.left {
  background: orange;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.right {
  background: #c0ffee;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.wrap.smaller {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <p class="left">Short Text</p>
  <p class="right">Much longer non-breaking text</p>
</div>

<div class="wrap smaller">
  <p class="left">Short Text</p>
  <p class="right">Much longer non-breaking text</p>
</div>
```

To see more, there's a whole video on it at [**CSS-Tricks**](https://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/140-exploring-css-layout-techniques-while-trying-to-get-a-subtitle-to-wrap/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query to fix that

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {  /* Put breaking size here like 480 */
     .right {
         float:left;
      }
  }
```

Comment: It won't work in this case, because both width's are dynamic!

Answer (score 0):

You can also play with jQuery

```js
var rightText = $(".right").outerWidth();
var leftText = $(".left").outerWidth();
var ulWidth  = $("ul").width();
if((rightText+leftText) > ulWidth)
 $(".right").css("float", "left");
```

```css
ul {width:250px; background:#ccc; display:block; margin-bottom:2em; clear:both;padding:0; list-style:inside none;}

 
.left {float:left; background:#2FCC71;}
.right {float:right; background:#3598DC;}

/* just for clearing floatt */
ul:before,
 ul:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
 }
 ul:after {
  clear:both;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<h2>Problem: long right element is right aligned</h2>
<ul>
  <li class="left">Left Element</li>
  <li class="right">Right Element with longer text</li>
</ul>
```